# Using parity check matrix to fix a hamming code error of one.

Tags: coding-theory

I thought I understood it right that if I multiply a erroneous code word with the parity check matrix(H) for a Hamming code, and the syndrome were non-zero, but matching one of the rows in H-matrix, I would simply change the bit, matching the row number?

That would mean that if I would again multiply that fixed codeword with the matrix H the result would be a zero-code-word, right?

I have been using Mathematica to solve for me and I have no idea why the fixed-code-word * H-Matrix is giving me another row in H, instead of zero:

````
H =
0011
0101
0110
0111
1001
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
1000
0100
0010
0001

wrongCode1 = Mod[{1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}.H,2]
wrongCode2 = Mod[{0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0}.H,2]
out = 1001 //Matching row 5 in H
out = 0110 // Matching row 3 in H

fixedCode1 = {1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0}
fixedCode2 = {0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0}

//Now test to see if I don't get zero when using fixedCode
 Mod[{1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0}.H,2]
 Mod[{0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0}.H,2]
 out = 0110 //Matching row 3 in H WHY!!
 out = 0010 // Matching row 14 in H WHY!!
```
````

Comment: In your first example the syndrome was the fifth row of $H$. So why did you change the tenth bit of the received vector instead of the fifth? In other words, you have to count the bit positions and the rows of $H$ starting from the same end. You counted bits starting from the last but rows of $H$ starting from the first.

Comment: Or, to make sure, you should have `fixedCode1={1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}`